# Why is echo outputting its flags to my redirect file?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash script...

```
MY_VAR=foobar

echo -n "$MY_VAR" > test.txt
```

When I run this script, text.txt contains...

```
-n foobar
```

When I run the same command in the terminal directly, I do not get the -n output.

How do I correct this?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate. Please share how are you calling this script.

Comment: Use printf instead.

Comment: See ["Why is `printf` better than `echo`?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) over on the Unix&Linux stackexchange. In this case, `printf '%s' "$MY_VAR" > test.txt` is the correct invocation.